# select Y if column if difference of count(colmn1) with value A and B is 0 using aggregate funtion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with table name **COM24** 
I have to select Y if there is a matching `movetype='C'` with `movetype='D'` and vice versa for the same **COM24**  `poliref`,`inrctyp`,`inrcref`,`csntype`,`duedate`,`itrno`.

What i am trying to do is as given below.
I am trying to explain the logic what i need, **I know the following will have error**

```
SELECT 'Y'
FROM  COM24  c2
HAVING  ( (COUNT(c2.movetype) = 'C')  - (COUNT(c2.movetype='D') ) ) =0  
AND c2.csnstat!= 90
GROUP BY  c2.poliref , c2.inrctyp , c2.inrcref , c2.csntype , c2.duedate , c2.itrno
```

So basically the requirement is if "count of movetyp with value 'C'" **-** "count of movetype with value 'D'" for the same `poliref`,`inrctyp`,`inrcref`,`csntype`,`duedate`,`itrno` is  0 then return Y

Comment: could you please deliver sample data of your table and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sum, you can achieve the results, there are many other ways to do so.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN SUM(CASE
                        WHEN c2.movetype = 'C' THEN
                         1
                        WHEN c2.movetype = 'D' THEN
                         -1
                        ELSE
                         0
                    END) = 0 THEN
            'Y'
           ELSE
            'N'
       END
  FROM com24 c2
 WHERE c2.csnstat != 90
 GROUP BY c2.poliref,
          c2.inrctyp,
          c2.inrcref,
          c2.csntype,
          c2.duedate,
          c2.itrno
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want the values in a cursor, you can write the code like this

```
CURSOR C1 AS
WITH t_table AS (
    SELECT c2.poliref,
           c2.inrctyp,
           c2.inrcref,
           c2.csntype,
           c2.duedate,
           c2.itrno,
           CASE
               WHEN SUM(CASE
                        WHEN c2.movetype = 'C' THEN
                         1
                        WHEN c2.movetype = 'D' THEN
                         -1
                        ELSE
                         0
                    END) = 0 THEN
            'Y'
           ELSE
            'N'
           END AS flag
      FROM com24 c2
     WHERE c2.csnstat != 90
     GROUP BY c2.poliref,
              c2.inrctyp,
              c2.inrcref,
              c2.csntype,
              c2.duedate,
              c2.itrno)
SELECT *
  FROM t_table       
 WHERE flag = 'Y';
```

> You requirement may be a little different but you can get some idea
>   from the answers on how to write your code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, 
But can i have this in the where clause , i have to use it in cursor , if cursor has no value then i have to do something ,   so i need  value in cursor only  if C - D  is greater than 0

Comment: Update the answer. If still it does not help the post the original requirement with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Hi, the original one , it is fetching hundreds of N  ,  i was expecting only one N or Y according to the requirement,  :-(  , it seems it is checking for each row and  giving Y or N , so i am getting so many  N as output

Comment: If you want to get only one record, then remove the group by clause, at present it will give you one row for each distinct value of c2.poliref, c2.inrctyp, c2.inrcref, c2.csntype, c2.duedate, c2.itrno combined.

Comment: I can't  give it in SELECT , as i have to fetch only specific columns in the cursor, the question posted here  just falls under one AND condition ,  if C - D = 0   then cursor should not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned you're using a cursor. I'd do something like this (Not tested yet) -

```
DECLARE
 cursor c1 is 
   select c2.poliref, c2.inrctyp, c2.inrcref, c2.csntype, c2.duedate, c2.itrno
   from com24 c2
   where c2.csnstat != 90
   and c2.movetype = 'C'
   minus
   select c2.poliref, c2.inrctyp, c2.inrcref, c2.csntype, c2.duedate, c2.itrno
   from com24 c2
   where c2.csnstat != 90
   and c2.movetype = 'D';

BEGIN
  open c1;
  fetch c1;
  if c1%notfound then
    /* Handle 'Y' return.. e.g: */
    dbms_output.put_line('Y');
  end if;
END;
/
```

Let me know if this is more or less what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, if it's a big table, and the data is distributed evenly more or less, having an index on "com24.movetype" could improve performance.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but i am selecting other things in the query , the question i have asked here is just one more  AND condition in  the current query , so basically its  -- other conditions query continues 
 AND  i need value in cursor only if C - D is greater than 0

Comment: I can't give it in SELECT , as i have to fetch only specific columns in the cursor, the question posted here just falls under one AND condition , if C - D = 0 then cursor should not return anything